# How to find volume of this foot

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

So I've learned integral calculus and by now I want to start actually using it for something.

So I thought to calculate the volume of my foot using integral calculus.

Here is a rough picture:

[image]

Obviously I can take any measurements I want (my foot is not this deformed either) so just ask in the comments and I will add them. If you have a better suggestion for the actual shape, do post it.

Question is: How would I calculate the volume of my foot now?

Comment: As a starting point I suggest applying the *spherical cow approximation* to your foot: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cow

Comment: That's your leg, not your foot. (At least, I hope it is.) Are you Russian? Or perhaps Hungarian?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how I made this mistake. I was thinking while writing: ''Remember to write leg, not foot'' but my brain must have mixed them up and went the exact wrong way.

Comment: Icelandic, though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, there are a number of ways to determine the volume of your foot (or your leg, as it appears in the picture) that do not rely on integral calculus - and most such answers would belong on a physics forum rather than a mathematics forum (simple experiments involving mass and density, or displaced fluid)

Even from a purely geometrical standpoint, the easiest method would be to split your leg and foot up into basic 3D shapes such as cylinders, wedges, cuboids, and spheres; and computing these volumes and adding them up.

However if you still want to use calculus, the best I can suggest is a refinement of the above method. Rather than approximating your leg as combination of simple geometric shapes, you can use a combination of more complex structures. [Surfaces of revolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_revolution) is a technique that could be useful, even though most body parts lack significant cylindrical symmetry. Another interesting thing to try would be taking a picture of the object you are trying to find the volume of, and fitting polynomial curve to the profile, and integrating under that curve.

If you want a really precise measurement of the volume of your foot using calculus, you could use a 3D modeling software such as [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) to reconstruct your foot, either from simple measurements or using more [advanced techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_reconstruction_from_multiple_images). Even though you will not get a chance to use your new calculus skills, rest assured that the software can numerically integrate the volume to give you a very good approximation of the true value.

Comment: Oh, okay. I thought people used integral calculus to find information like this and I was hoping of getting my hands dirty with some ''advanced'' subjects at last.

Comment: But it's actually nice to know that people would do it the way I originally did it in the real world, so that's something.

Comment: People do use integral calculus, but just more numerical integration (Riemann sums), rather than analytical calculus. This is mainly because it is hard to find simple functions to approximate complex shapes, and if you want a definite integral, you don't really care about the anti-derivative.

Answer (score 1):

For measuring you'll need bucket and bigger bucket. Put the bigger bucket on the floor. Put the smaller bucket into bigger bucket. Fill the smaller bucket with water till top and put your foot into it. Measure the volume of displaced water in the bigger bucket. :)

Comment: You can also use tub, like Archimedes

Comment: This is a very good and very accurate solution with absolutely no assumptions. Congratulations.

Answer (score 1):

You can model the leg as having a circular cross section everywhere except the foot.  If you measure the diameter (or, more easily with a tape measure, the circumference) at a number of points, you can model each slice as a [conical frustum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConicalFrustum.html).  Then estimate the volume of the front part of the foot, which will be a small part of the total so an error here won't matter too much.